# How to install flareGet_1.0-1(beta)_deb_rpm.tar.gz?

Tags: installation

I wanted to install Flarget. I visted the website and dowloaded the the file

```
flareGet_1.0-1(beta)_deb_rpm.tar.gz
```

and saved it in the location

```
/home/suhailcholassery/Download/flareGet_1.0-1(beta)_deb_rpm.tar.gz
```

How do I go about installing it? I tried typing the following command in terminal as per the readme's instruction enclosed in file.

```
yum install flareGet-1.0-1.i386.rpm
```

but the reply was the following:

> You need to be root to perform this command

And I don't know how that is to be done. Isn't there any simpler way for installing this package?

Comment: flareGet is available in Ubuntu Software Center, search for the package and click install!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Tutorial: Step by Step**

1. Go to http://www.flareget.com/download/ and download the newest version of the program.
2. After download finished you will have a .tar.gz file, but note that this is not the source code.
3. Extract it with a right click and choosing "Extract Here", after that you'll see a two folders: one called "debs" and another called "RPMS", open the "debs" folder. Or if you'd like to use the Terminal to do that you can run the following command:

   `$ tar xzvf flareget_[version]_deb_rpm.tar.gz`
4. If your system is 32 bits install the package flareGet_[version]*i386.deb, else if it's 64 bits install the package flareget*[version]_amd64.deb.
5. In both cases to install it you can use GDebi Package Installer, by right clicking on the package and choosing "GDebi Package Installer" or from the Terminal with the following command:

Go to the folder "debs".

32 bits:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i flareget_[version]_i386.deb
```

64 bits:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i flareget_[version]_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu, then simply double click the deb package (i386 for 32-bit or amd64 for 64-bit) and it will install automatically using Ubuntu Software Center.

Make sure you are connected to internet, in case dependencies are not satisfied, it will automatically download them for internet.